# ATI Radeon Xpress 1250 not supported for Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

When I try to download Windows 10, I get a messge saying that Windows 10 cannot be installed because the current Windows 7 ATI Radeon Xpress 1250 display driver is not supported.  According to driverscape.com there is a ATI Radeon Xpress 1250 Version 8.5 that supports Windows 10.  Is it safe to download the Version 8.5 on my Windows 7 before downloading Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall your graphics driver and then upgrade to Windows 10. Then once that's done, you can install the updated graphics driver. It just means that you won't have a working graphics driver once the Windows 10 installation finishes. Windows will revert to a basic VGA driver if there is no other suitable graphics driver installed. You'll have a low resolution and no 3D acceleration, but you will still be able to see the desktop and use the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the manufacturer's website to see it the display TRUELY supports windows 10. If it does, upgrade to v.e. 8.5 and go for windows 10. Remeber, You can always go back to windows 7/8/8.1 if it doesn't work.